# VS Code no reconoce el emulador de Android

Tags: android, flutter, vscode

estoy creando una aplicación en Flutter, pero a la hora de crearla VS Code no reconoce el emulador de Android. Uso Android Studio para arrancar el emulador y lo selecciono en VS Code. He revisado las características de Windows y tengo desactivado el Hyper-V. ¿Alguien sabe como solucionarlo?
En VS Code, a la hora de seleccionar un emulador me sale que el emulador que descargué esta offline.

Comment: Puedes poner el resultado de flutter doctor?

Comment: No me salta ningún error, esta todo con un tick verde

Answer (score 0):

puedes probar abriendo Android Studio y ver que tengas todo esto instalado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Normalmente he visto que a muchos les ocurre por no tener instalado alguna de estas herramientas.